# IE8 table float and parent Div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

In IE8, I have a parent div with 3 child tables. I want the tables to be next to each other and for the parent div to have an overflow on the x-axis so that the user can scroll on the parent div to see the next table. 
HTML:

```
<div id="q_box">'
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
    <table>         
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
    <table> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
         </tr>
    <table>
```

and the CSS:

```
#q_box{
    position:relative;
    height:120px;width:100px;
    background:red;
    float:right;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
#q_box table{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

Code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tech_noob/aYAwe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add another div.  Your top level container sets the width and overflow like you've done with `#q_box`.  The next div (the new one) has an extra wide width to accommodate the tables floating to the left:

```
#wrap {
  width: 1000em;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aYAwe/1/

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to not use the float left css and instead use display inline block. This then allows you to apply a white-space nowrap to the parent div.

```
#q_box{
    position:relative;
    height:120px;width:100px;
    background:red;
    float:right;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#q_box table{
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

I have updated you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYAwe/2/).

Please note that this inline block does not work in IE 7. You can use display: inline and give the element the hasLayout with, for example, zoom: 1;